# What happens to the steady state of the series RC circuit if changes happen to any circuit element?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, transient, steady-state

The question that I'm trying to understand is the following:

> In any series RC circuit that is in steady state, WHEN any of the
> elements **changes** (R, C, or applied voltage), the following will happen to the
> circuit:
>
> (A) The circuit will briefly operate in steady state then gradually go
> on a transient state.
>
> (B) The circuit will immediately go on a
> transient state then reach a steady state.
>
> (C) The circuit will
> immediately go to a transient state.

My answer is B since, according to the textbook, the transient response is a circuit's temporary response that will die out with time and the steady-state response stays for a long time after an external excitation is applied. Now, is that external excitation include changes in any of the circuit elements?

Comment: *WHEN any of the elements (R, C, or applied voltage)* what? when they do what?

Comment: @Andyaka, when they 'change.' Sorry, I edited the question already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *My answer is B*

It all depends how they *change* - if they change to a new static value(s) then "B" is the answer. If they change and continue to change then "C" might be the answer.

> *My answer is B since, according to the textbook, the transient
> response is a circuit's temporary response that will die out with time
> and the steady-state response stays for a long time after an external
> excitation is applied.*

Then there's the consideration of AC transient response.

If the input voltage becomes a sinewave i.e. is continuously changing sinusoidally, then the AC response on the output has a transient response leading to a non-static steady-state response because, the output will also "become" a sinewave (with phase shift) after the transient response has died down.

So, it all depends what you mean.